# Show the O-notation for the following code fragment

Tags: big-o

The question is to Show the O-notation for the following code fragments (show each line)

```
for x=1 to n
    {
        y=1
        while y < n
        y=y+y
    }
```

The O notation for the first line is n, I believe.
I am unsure what the O notation is for the while loop and why?

The answer given is O(n log <sub>2</sub>n )

Can someone please explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume n=64 (or 2<sup>6</sup>), then the while loop will run 6 times with the following final value of y:

2
4
8
16
32
64

If you repeat this for n=256 (or 2<sup>8</sup>), you will find that there are 8 iterations. In more general terms the number of executions for a given value of n will be log <sub>2</sub>n. As the outer loop is n, the total execution time is O(n log <sub>2</sub>n )

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop y takes the values 1, 2, 4...

y is multiplied by 2 each time so it is of the form 2^k

This loop stops for the largest value k such as 2^k < n i.e. k < log_2(n)

There will be no more than log_2 (n) iterations in this loop

x ranging from 1 to n, may increase the total number of iteration by n.log_2(n)